# loggin postgresql when others exception

Tags: postgresql

Database: RDS PostgreSQL 12
I have a simeple proc that errors out. When it errors out I would like to log a record of it and then raise the exception. However I can only get it to do one of those things. I can either get it to log the error or I can raise the exception. I've tried both inserting the record directly from the exception block or by calling a proc that will insert the record into the table. How can I get it to do both? I'll post the code for the two blocks below. Any help would be appreciated!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE error_test_prc () 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $body$
DECLARE
    var1 int;
BEGIN
    SELECT 10/0 INTO var1;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        --INSERT INTO mdm_raw.raw_err_msg(msg_date, msg) VALUES(current_date, 'test');
        CALL mdm_raw.error_logging_prc('this is a different proc test');
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Caught in Block 1 %', SQLERRM;
END;
$body$
```

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE error_logging_prc (msg_text text) 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $body$
DECLARE
    var1 int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mdm_raw.raw_err_msg(msg_date, msg) VALUES(current_date, msg_text);
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error Caught in error_logging_prc %', SQLERRM;
END;
$body$
```

Comment: Sorry that is hard to read, the formatting got lost in the post

Comment: To format or maintain the format of your code highlight it and click the {} icon at the top or press Ctrl+K or put a line containing just ``` both before and after the code.

Answer (score 0):

The only known way to achieve that is to use the dblink extension to create a new connection from the database to itself. You can write your log message via dblink and commit it, then throw the error that will roll back the current transaction.

Comment: Laurenz, can you add an example of how to use the dblink, I have not had much luck getting it to work

Comment: The documentation [has examples](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/contrib-dblink-exec.html), and I couldn't do better.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this by rollback on the current transaction, then insert and commit your log. See lines marked with --<<<<< in your procedure below. Another would be setting up a dblink.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE error_test_prc () 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $body$
DECLARE
    var1 int;
BEGIN
    SELECT 10/0 INTO var1;
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        declare                             --<<<<<<
           msg text                         --<<<<<<
        begin                               --<<<<<<
            msg = sqlerrm;                  --<<<<<<
            rollback;                       --<<<<<<
            CALL mdm_raw.error_logging_prc('this is a different proc test');   
            RAISE EXCEPTION 'Caught in Block 1 %',msg;
        end ;
END;
$body$


CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE error_logging_prc msg_text text) 
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $body$
DECLARE
    var1 int;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO mdm_raw.raw_err_msg(msg_date, msg) VALUES(current_date, msg_text);
    commit;              --<<<<<< 
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN 
        RAISE EXCEPTION 'Error Caught in error_logging_prc %', SQLERRM;
END;
$body$
```

Comment: Sorry, Belayer. I could not get that to work. It didnt like the commit in the logging proc and having the rollback did not work to insert the record.